How to break axis in GNUplot
I wish to break Y-axis between 0.3 and 2.3. My code is:
reset session

$Singlets <<EOD
0   0.000
1   2.652
2   2.704
3   2.842
EOD

$Triplets <<EOD
1   2.511
2   2.547
3   2.580
4   2.618
5   2.826
6   2.836
EOD

unset xtic
set offset 0.25,0.25
set key noautotitle
set ylabel "Energy / eV"

#set arrow from 0.5,1.1 to 1,0.9 lc "black"
#set label 1 "k_{ISC}=" at 0.75, 1.0

# Adjust the scale factor as needed for vector length
vector_scale = 0.5  # Set this to your desired length factor

# Define separation between singlets and triplets
triplet_x_offset = 0.75  # Horizontal distance between singlets and triplets

set arrow from 1,0.8 to 1,0  heads size screen 0.05,90
set label 1 "{/Symbol D}E=" at 1.1 , 0.25 rotate 90

# Plot with vectors, existing labels, and Y-values centered above each vector
plot $Singlets u (0):2:(1*vector_scale):(0) w vectors lw 2 lc "red" nohead, \
     '' u (0):2:(sprintf("S_%d", $1)) w labels offset -1.5,0, \
     '' u (0.25):2:(sprintf("%.2f", $2)) w labels offset 0,0.5, \
     $Triplets u (triplet_x_offset):2:(1*vector_scale):(0) w vectors lw 2 lc "blue" nohead, \
     '' u (triplet_x_offset+0.50):2:(sprintf("T_%d", $1)) w labels offset 1.5,0, \
     '' u (triplet_x_offset+0.25):2:(sprintf("%.2f", $2)) w labels offset 0,0.50

I tried to achieve it with multiplot but without a success. The script just didn’t work or broke this working one. I would like to annotate also the breaking somehow (eg. Double backlash or tilde)
Thanks !

Have you for example checked this or this?

Problem solved? Is your question a duplicate of one of the links above?
